# Find name using like operator in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have table with columns

```
surname    forename
Dane jr    Carlo
Dane Br    Carlo
Daniel     Gerard
```

`forename` should be same and surname partially same (means string before space  should be same after space should not same)

Output like

```
surname    forename
Dane jr    Carlo
Dane Br    Carlo
```

Comment: so you want to match parts of the name, excluding anything after the spaces in surname?

Comment: this is just example i want all the matched forename

Comment: this is just example i want all the matched forename and half of the sure name should be same (means string appears after space should not same   before space should same)

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
c.* from table c
join
(select substring(surname,1,charindex(' ',surname,1)) as namee,forename from table
group by
substring(surname,1,charindex(' ',surname,1)),forename
having count(*)>1
) b
on c.surname like '%'+b.namee+'%'
and c.forename=b.forename
```

**one more approach :**

```
;with cte
as
(
select *,count(*) over (partition by substring(surname,1,charindex(' ',surname,1)),forename ) as cnt
from table
)
select * from cte  where cnt>1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, please test it with a larger dataset though. It will return any rows where the names appear more than once. It matches rows based on the forename and the first part of the surname (before the space, if one exists).

```
CREATE TABLE #names
    (
      surname NVARCHAR(50) ,
      forename NVARCHAR(50)
    );

INSERT  INTO #names
        ( surname, forename )
VALUES  ( 'Dane jr', 'Carlo' ),
        ( 'Dane Br', 'Carlo' ),
        ( 'Daniel', 'Gerard' );

SELECT  surname ,
        n1.forename
FROM    #names n1
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT LEFT(surname, CHARINDEX(' ', surname)) FirstPartSurname ,
                            forename
                     FROM   #names
                   ) n2 ON n2.forename = n1.forename
                           AND n1.surname LIKE n2.FirstPartSurname + '%'
GROUP BY n1.surname ,
        n1.forename
HAVING  COUNT(1) > 1;


DROP TABLE #names;
```

Produces:

```
surname  forename
Dane Br  Carlo
Dane jr  Carlo
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
Declare @tbl table(surname varchar(30),forename varchar(30))
insert into @tbl(surname,forename)values
('Dane jr','Carlo'),
('Dane Br','Carlo'),
('Daniel','Gerard')

select a.surname,forename from
(select sdx,rcount,surname,forename from
(select soundex(surname) as sdx,row_number() over(partition by soundex(surname) order by soundex(surname)) as rcount, surname,forename from @tbl) as a
) as a
right join

(select sdx,rcount,surname from
(select soundex(surname) as sdx,row_number() over(partition by soundex(surname) order by soundex(surname)) as rcount, surname from @tbl) as a
where rcount >1)  as b
on a.sdx = b.sdx
```

Output:

```
Dane jr Carlo
Dane Br Carlo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE (namee, forename) AS (
select  LEFT(surname,charindex(' ',surname,1)) as namee, forename
from tabTestName
group by forename, LEFT(surname,charindex(' ',surname,1)) having count(*)>1 
) select t.* from CTE join tabTestName t
```

on t.surname like '%'+CTE.namee+'%'
and t.forename=CTE.forename

Answer (score 0):

i have added id column for this

Dane Br    Carlo           2
Daniel     Gerard          3                                                                              Moore Jr         A           4                                                                              Moore Jr         A           5                                                                                                                                                                       i need this as out put                                                                      surname    forename  id
Dane jr    Carlo            1
Dane Br    Carlo           2                                                                                  but the out put shows                                                                                    surname    forename  id
Dane jr    Carlo            1
Dane Br    Carlo           2                                                                                  Moore Jr         A           4                                                                              Moore Jr         A           5